# Bash shell script postprocessing results of ls

Tags: string, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I came across a shell script like the following:

```
for FILE_PATH in `ls some/directory`
do
    export FILE=${FILE_PATH##*/}
done
```

What exactly is the "##*/" doing? When I echo ${FILE} and ${FILE_PATH}, I don't see any difference. Is this to handle unusually named files?

More generally, how would I go about figuring out this type of question for myself in the future? Google was completely useless.

Comment: For anything to do with Bash, if you don't know the term to search for, searching the [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is often a good idea. `##` shows up under [*Shell parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's removing everything up to the last `/` in the value of `$FILE`. From the [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> `${parameter#word}`
> `${parameter##word}`
> The `word` is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see Pattern Matching). If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value of `parameter`, then the result of the expansion is the value of `parameter` with the shortest matching pattern (the `‘#’` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `‘##’` case) deleted.

You're not seeing any difference in this case because when you list a directory it just outputs the filenames, it doesn't include the directory portion, so there's nothing to remove. You would see the difference if you did:

```
for FILE in some/directory/*
```